# How to dump commands for current plot

Tags: gnuplot

In interactive mode gnuplot remembers all the settings for the current plot. It knows what to do when I type 'replot'. So, is there a way to dump all of the current settings into a script file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the `save` command.

You use it as follows:

```
save "My_stuff_goes_to_this_file.txt"
```

Here's a (small) excerpt from the docs:

> The `save` command saves user-defined functions, variables, the `set
>   term` status, all `set` options, or all of these, plus the last `plot`
>   (`splot`) command to the specified file.
>
> Syntax:
>         save  {option} 'filename'