# Save all past gnuplot command line input to file

Tags: gnuplot

I sometimes find myself having created some gnuplot plot in interactive mode and wanting to save it (i.e. a script creating it) for later use. Is there a way to tell gnuplot to dump all the lines (that did not produce an error) of the current session into a file? Or do I have to retype everything?

Comment: Use `save 'file'` to save the current status.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11211788/2604213